# Subsetting values from two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'C']
b = ['C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'E', 'C']
```

And I want to subset these to get:

```
a = ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']
b = ['C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']
```

Such that I keep the 'E' from the first list, but get the respective positional values using indices from the second list b.

I tried to use:

```
a = [x for x in a if x == 'E']
b = [x for x in b if x == 'E']
```

But this doesn't keep the order/position, instead it extracts just E from list b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use zip function to zip and then unzip like this

```py
a = ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'C']
b = ['C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'E', 'C']

a, b = zip(*[(ai, bi) for ai, bi in zip(a,b) if ai=="E"])
print(a)
print(b)
```

**Output**

```
('E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E')
('C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) feature:

```
from itertools import takewhile

a = ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'C']
b = ['C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'E', 'C']

a_slice = list(takewhile(lambda x: x == 'E', a))
b_slice = b[:len(a_slice)]

print(a_slice)   # ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']
print(b_slice)   # ['C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason this doesnt work on my longer lists, the lists in the question are dummy lists.

Comment: @HajSai, instead of *dummy lists* post a more actual input samples

Comment: this doesn't work if there are "C"s before last "E", like at start

Comment: The actual list is 33452 values long that's why I didn't post it.

Comment: @HajSai, then, this approach is working for your posted input. I'm not telling you to post the entire 33452 long list, but post a more **representative** input list that covers **extended** conditions

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = [x for x in a if x == 'E']

indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == "E"]

b = [b[i] for i in indexes]
```

Comment: this is also not working try with this input 
```a = ['C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'C', 'C']
b = ['E', 'C', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'E', 'C']```

Comment: Try this 

indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == "E"]

b = [b[i] for i in indexes]

a = [x for x in a if x == 'E']